# OpenMP - using functions

Tags: c++, openmp

When I am using OpenMP without functions with the `reduction(+ : sum)` , the OpenMP version works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;

int sum = 0;
void summation()
{
    sum = sum + 1;
}

int main()
{
    int i,sum;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction (+ : sum)
    for(i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
        summation();

#pragma omp parallel for reduction (+ : sum)
    for(i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
        summation();

#pragma omp parallel for reduction (+ : sum)
    for(i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
        summation();

    std::cerr << "Sum is=" << sum << std::endl;
}
```

But when I am calling a function `summation` over a global variable, the OpenMP version is taking even more time than the sequential version.

I would like to know the reason for the same and the changes that should be made.

Answer (score 0):

The `summation` function doesn't use the OMP shared variable that you are reducing to. Fix it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

void summation(int& sum) { sum++; }

int main()
{
    int sum;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction (+ : sum)
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i)
        summation(sum);

    std::cerr << "Sum is=" << sum << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The time taken to synchronize the access to this one variable will be way in excess of what you gain by using multiple cores- they will all be endlessly waiting on each other, because there is only one variable and only one core can access it at a time. This design is not capable of concurrency and all the sync you're paying will just increase the run-time.